# In Activity Monitor, is the percentage out of each core or out of each virtual core?

Tags: macbook-pro, performance, activity-monitor, macos, processor

I have my new MacBook Pro [with 2 cores](http://pbrd.co/1amwfLu).

However, [the Activity Monitor shows me 4 “virtual” cores](http://pbrd.co/1amxdHH). (I don’t really know what a “virtual core” is.)

If the processor is running at maximum, what percentages for processes would I have in Activity Monitor ?

- A total of 200 % ?
- A total of 400 % ?

Comment: @grgarside — Related question, but not a duplicate. It seems that the answer by Jake I got here is rather an answer for the other question.

Comment: Ok, I've retracted my close vote and posted a direct answer. Is there a reason for your rollback of my edit embedding the screenshots?

Comment: @grgarside — I prefer to leave the images as links, they are less parasitic this way (the message is kept to the point), they are really not essential to the understanding of my message. Furthermore, there were accessibility problems in their embedding code and their site was not reliable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CPU percentages shown in Activity Monitor are 100% for each virtual core.

**Therefore, for your hyper-threaded dual-core processor, 400% is 100%.**

In my case, the hyper-threaded quad-core in my Mac means that 800% is 100%.

Answer (score 1):

The answer—[as explained here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54502/why-does-apple-activity-monitor-report-that-my-mac-with-a-dual-core-intel-i5-ivy)—is because of [hyperthreading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading). 1 CPU with 2 cores and 4 virtual cores. Your MacBook Pro (Mid 2012)—as per the screenshot that ids it as “MacBookPro 9,2”—uses a 2.9GHz dual-core Intel Core i7 processor. The i5 & i7 processors use [hyperthreading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading).

**EDIT** CPU percentage on multi-core systems is 100% multiplied by the number of cores.  If you have 4 cores, your CPU running at max will be 400%.

Comment: So ? What is the answer ?

Comment: Your answer contradicts what @grgarside says. I think grgarside is right.